# Prove the given equality for every polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional $K$-vector space, let $$\alpha ∈ End_k(V)$$ be a $K$-endomorphism of $V$ , and let $S$ be a $K$-basis of $V$ .

Prove that for every polynomial $f \in K[X]$ one has the equality: 
$$ M_{S,S}(f(\alpha)) = f(M_{S,S}(\alpha))$$

I think I need to fix a polynomial and then work on the given equality by focusing on the input and output of matrix $M$ which is $S$. Could you please give me a hint on how to prove it ? I really do not know from where to begin?

Comment: Basically, this is asking to show that expressing an endomorphism by a square matrix on a given basis is a $K$ algebra isomorphism (that is, $K$-linear and compatible with composition). That is pretty basic.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we can start by proving then using the following:
\begin{align*}
M_{s, s}(\alpha + \beta) &= M_{s, s}(\alpha) + M_{s, s}(\beta) \\
M_{s, s}(\alpha\beta) &= M_{s, s}(\alpha) M_{s, s}(\beta) \\
M_{s, s}(k \alpha) &= k M_{s, s}(\alpha),
\end{align*}
for any endomorphisms $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and any scalar $k$. You can use induction and the second equality to show that $M_{s, s}(\alpha^n) = (M_{s, s}(\alpha))^n$ for any $n$. You can then use the third equality to show that the result holds for any monomial function (i.e. a function of the form $f(x) = kx^n$). Finally, you can use induction a second time to prove that the result works for sums of monomials, a.k.a. polynomials!

Comment: Induction is the only way? 
Should I check the three properties of a vector space: if it contains the zero vector, if it is closed under addition and lastly if it is closed under scalar multiplication .... however, this action should only prove that an arbitrary polynomial is a subspace of the K-vector space.

Comment: This is not about showing something is a vector space (I'm not sure what you mean about polynomials being subspaces). What we're showing here is that the map $M_{s, s}$ is an algebra homomorphism: it respects vector addition, vector multiplication, and scalar multiplication. It's a linear map, but more, since it respects multiplication too. In this way, the map preserves more than just linear combinations, but polynomials.